# Align divs with images horizontally and be able to scroll through them horizontally

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to make a website that look like I am driving through various cities.

As I scroll through the  webpage horizontally the images keep changing in the background.

[Some thing like this, but I want to add the images as a div and not an image.](http://dm.ampd.yorku.ca/~shad344/datt1939/a1/)

[here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLZjd/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div style="height:400px; width:100%; clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://www.japaneseammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bigstock-Mt-Fuji-with-fall-colors-in-j-48491102.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://www.japaneseammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bigstock-Mt-Fuji-with-fall-colors-in-j-48491102.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
        <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://www.japaneseammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bigstock-Mt-Fuji-with-fall-colors-in-j-48491102.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
            <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://www.japaneseammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bigstock-Mt-Fuji-with-fall-colors-in-j-48491102.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
                <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://www.japaneseammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bigstock-Mt-Fuji-with-fall-colors-in-j-48491102.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- Image of me just standing or probably an image created in Sketch -->
    <div id="my-">

    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
    .container{ 
    width:50%; 
    margin:0 auto; 
}
.container span{ 
    width:30%; 
    margin:0 1%;  
}
#walking-man{
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is that what you already made?

Comment: @Kristine no its not what I made, its something I found online . . .

Comment: Could you add a fiddle or something that you have already tried?

Comment: From what you have written, make background div overflow-x: scroll, white-space: nowrap; width: as long as needed, and put a background-image. Make that image long, with all of the cities in one line.
And iv on the front- fixed. Also: if you want several divs in line, make them display: inline-block;

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wSfJd/

Comment: @Kristine that is exactly what I want, could you make that an answer so  i could upvote it ? :) but can I add images of different lengths ?

Comment: Use background-image: url("paper.gif") in div tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple html:

```
<div class="background">
    <img src="your image" alt="">
    <img src="your image" alt="">
    <img src="your image" alt="">
    <img src="your image" alt="">
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
.background {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.background img {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f67ph3bt/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: (and yes, the images can be different width!)

```
<ul class="images">
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" width="auto" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" width="auto" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" width="auto" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" width="auto" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" width="auto" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" width="auto" height="150"/></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" width="auto" height="150"/></a></li>
</ul>
<style>
ul.images {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
ul.images li {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wSfJd/